# Regex Patter on EditTextby using setTextValidationis not working properly

Tags: java, android, regex, android-edittext, edit

I am using setTextValidation on EditText with regex pattern but it's not working properly. I only need alphabets & space for the field but when I press numbers it copies the other alphabets which is typed previously.

```
        ValidationUtil.setTextValidation(etClientMiddleName, "[a-zA-Z ]+", 50);
```

This is `setTextValidation` method

```
 public static void setTextValidation(EditText mEdtField, final String mRegExp, int length) {
    try {
        InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
            @Override
            public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
                String data = source.toString().substring(start, end);
                String retData = null;
                boolean isValid = false;
                isValid = data.matches(mRegExp);
                if (!isValid) {
                    if (source instanceof SpannableStringBuilder) {
                        retData = data.replaceAll("[\\d]", "");
                    } else {
                        retData = "";
                    }
                }
                return retData;
            }
        };

        mEdtField.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter, new InputFilter.LengthFilter(length)});
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Text Validation", "" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `ValidationUtil.setTextValidation` method? I don't see it in any framework.

Comment: Forgot to mention I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed input type of my EditText

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
```

Also Tried the following but didn't worked for me

```
android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try filtering disallowed characters like this.

```
ValidationUtil.setTextValidation(etClientMiddleName, "[^a-zA-Z ]", 50);
```

---

```
@Override
public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
    String data = source.toString().substring(start, end);
    return data.replaceAll(mRegExp,"");
}
```

Comment: it's not working when I press any digit it copies the previously typed alphabet.

Comment: Did you try debugging the value of `data` in the `filter` method? Because It didn't happen for me even with your previous approach.

The approach in my answer takes the input text ( typed or pasted ), and only removes the characters that are not alphabet or space.

Also, Please note that the regex in my answer slightly differs from the question.